# How to do subplots when plot_histogram etc. closes the figure

Tags: qiskit

I would like to display two histograms next to each other, using something like matplotlib's subplot function. This doesn't seem to work because plot_histogram() closes the figure.

It is possible to show a figure that has been closed - see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729948/matplotlib-how-to-show-a-figure-that-has-been-closed). I tried this approach but it doesn't work (see code below). Does anyone know how to do this?

```
figs = []
for i in range(num):
    counts = result.get_counts(circuits[i])
    figs.append(plot_histogram(counts, title='here', bar_labels=True))
    print(counts)
plt.subplot(121)
new_fig = plt.figure()
new_mngr = new_fig.canvas.manager
new_mngr.canvas.figure = figs[0]
fig.set_canvas(new_mngr.canvas)
plt.show(fig)

plt.subplot(122)
new_fig = plt.figure()
new_mngr = new_fig.canvas.manager
new_mngr.canvas.figure = figs[1]
fig.set_canvas(new_mngr.canvas)
plt.show(fig)
```

Comment: If stopping `plot_histogram()` from closing the figure will fix this issue, then there is a way to do just that. If you go into the qiskit code to `qiskit/visualization/counts_visualization.py` you will find the `plot_histrogram()` method. Near the end of this method, you will see the conditional statement `if fig: plt.close(fig)`. If you comment that out, it should stop automatically closing the figure when you call `plot_histogram()`

Comment: I am reluctant to modify the qiskit code because there is some discussion about why qiskit chose to close the figure in this [github issue](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/1682)

Comment: John , it is true that there is discussion going on about why it originally is being closed. However, modifying the code in this way should not be detrimental. If any change is ever made to the way the figure is displayed, it would be pushed in a new version of qiskit. Then you would just need to update and it would take and use the new code.

@glS I can move the comment to be an answer. Wasn't sure at first if it matched exactly what John was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*~Moved from comment to answer~*

If stopping `plot_histogram()` from closing the figure will fix this issue, then there is a way to do just that. If you go into the qiskit code to `qiskit/visualization/counts_visualization.py` you will find the `plot_histrogram()` method. Near the end of this method, you will see the conditional statement

```
if fig: 
    plt.close(fig)
```

If you comment that out, it should stop automatically closing the figure when you call `plot_histogram()`.